# Force crosswalk to save cookies

Tags: android, cordova, cookies, synchronization, crosswalk

So I'm using crosswalk for a cordova android app, and from what I [understand](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-6321?focusedCommentId=49058&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-49058), if a cookie is sent from the server - it may take a few seconds for it to be synced (saved) in crosswalk's cache\memory, thus if a cookie is set and the user closes the app immediately - it is as if it wasn't set at all.

This is a bad situation for me because I really need to use a secure httponly cookie and not let the javascript get it (to avoid XSS and whatnot).

Is there any way to force sync\save the cookies, preferably using javascript or even if needed then native code?

EDIT: I'd probably be fine with firing the "flush" method in here from the javascript (and I don't mind building a plugin for that): https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/blob/master/platforms/android/src/org/crosswalk/engine/XWalkCordovaCookieManager.java

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am working on a similar problem and I wonder how you have solved it? I am using a heavily changed version of [this plugin](https://github.com/Shoety/cordova-plugin-inappbrowserxwalk). Just for testing, on each load stop event I am calling `flushCookieStore()` but still after closing the app, cookies are not persisted. Can you maybe share some example code? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response (only now i saw it), I've written a simple plugin for cordova and able to force flush the cookies.

Comment: because the regular flush cookies method just doesn't do anything (really, it's actually empty iirc). i can prolly give it to you if you need it, but i don't seem to find a pm option in stackoverflow, so just poke me if you need it.